# create interface a should it really need to have interface a or i can implement in this class

Tags: java, interface

if I create `interface a {...}` should I really make a new class called a or it is ok to be implemented in the current class using `class b implement a`. If it can be in the current class, how do I call it when I need to use the interface in other classes?

```
interface Formatter {
   String format(String string);


    class IdentityFormatter implements Formatter {
       @Override public String format(String string) { return string; }
    }
}
```

it seems to be done in the same current class but I wonder if I do need a concrete interface for my a.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I haven't a clue as to what your actual question is. Please use a real example and explain it better.

Comment: I, personally, think it's a bad idea to nest a concrete implementation in an `interface`; but you would say `a.b` - because `class b` (if it is inside `interface a`) **is** `static`.

Comment: The snipped is missing a closing bracket making it unclear whether the class is nested in the interface or not

Comment: @david i actually don't know that either I read that from separate pages so i said it seem in the same class

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. My answer only applies if you are trying to play with the below code:

```
interface Formatter {
   String format(String string);
}

class IdentityFormatter implements Formatter {
   @Override public String format(String string) { return string; }
}
```

IMHO, you should put the interface into a `Formatter.java` file and put the concrete class implementing it into another. Because you can only have one of them to be `public` and be used out of the current package.

**update:**

put interface `Formatter` into `Formatter.java`, and put class `IdentityFormatter` into another `IdentityFormatter.java`. Making both of them public by adding `public` keyword.

Comment: Stated reason is not correct. Everything contained in an interview is implicitly public.

Comment: Look at the sample code, is it possible that both of the interface and the concrete class public?

Comment: The PO is trying to define an interface and an class in the same file. So only one of them can be `public`

Comment: Do you mean put interface Formatter {String format(String string); in the interface called Formatter and this one is done, all the other code should be in other class?

Comment: The code is missing a closing bracket making it unclear whether PO ment to put the class as nested in the interface or just placed in the same file.

Comment: The nested class is already public, for the reason I gave, and any interface can be public. Try it if you don't believe. Don't just keep repeating your error.

Comment: NB Typo alert in my first comment. Everything contained in an *interface* is already implicitly public, and can be explicitly so marked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your requirement and code security. you can write Default method or Static method in Interfaces and you can use them in classes. As per your sample code You wanted to write Formatter ( or like Logger) so you can write these kind of methods in Interface.

Refer Java documentation.  Here's [a link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Comment: Thank you and the link.